# How to select next row in QTableView programmatically

Tags: c++, qt

I have `QTableView` subclass that I am marking and saving its state with this :

```
connect(this,
        SIGNAL(clicked(const QModelIndex &)),
        this,
        SLOT(clickedRowHandler(const QModelIndex &))
    );

void PlayListPlayerView::clickedRowHandler(const QModelIndex & index)
{
    int iSelectedRow = index.row();
    QString link = index.model()->index(index.row(),0, index.parent()).data(Qt::UserRole).toString();
    emit UpdateApp(1,link );
}
```

now i like programmatically to move the selection to the next row (not by pressing the row with the mouse)
and invoking `clickedRowHandler(...)` how shall i do that ?
Thanks

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You already have the current row index, so use something like the following to get the modelindex for the next row

```
QModelIndex next_index = table->model()->index(row + 1, 0);
```

Then you can set that modelindex as the current one using

```
table->setCurrentIndex(next_index);
```

Obviously you'll need to make sure you're not running past the end of the table, and there's probably some extra steps to make sure the entire row is selected, but that should get you closer.

Comment: Thanks for the replay , how do i make it be selected ( with the blue color on the row?

Comment: table->selectionModel()->select( index, QItemSelectionModel::ClearAndSelect|QItemSelectionModel::Rows )

Comment: Hello, who knows how select next/previous row skipping non-selectable rows? So it'll emulate down/up arrows pressing. Code above doesn't work when model has rows without Qt::ItemIsSelectable or Qt::ItemIsEnabled flags.

Answer (score 2):

```
/*
 * selectNextRow() requires a row based selection model.
 * selectionMode = SingleSelection
 * selectionBehavior = SelectRows
 */

void MainWindow::selectNextRow( QTableView *view )
{
    QItemSelectionModel *selectionModel = view->selectionModel();
    int row = -1;
    if ( selectionModel->hasSelection() )
        row = selectionModel->selection().first().indexes().first().row();
    int rowcount = view->model()->rowCount();
    row = (row + 1 ) % rowcount;
    QModelIndex newIndex = view->model()->index(row, 0);
    selectionModel->select( newIndex, QItemSelectionModel::ClearAndSelect );
}
```