# Initital highlight of QTableWidget

Tags: qt4

I have created an application using QTableWidget in qt4. My problem is that as soon as I run the program, the position of highlighter should be at a cell which is defined by me(say at cell (1,0)). How to achieve this?? Please guide me.

Thanks in advance,
Chaitanya

Answer (score 0):

Use [setCurrentIndex](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qabstractitemview.html#setCurrentIndex). [This other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9678138/how-to-select-next-row-in-qtableview-programmatically) should help you out (just specify the cell index other than row's one).